# SCP, download a file from website to local pc

Tags: putty, scp

I am using putty to connect to the website. I know how to copy a file from a website to my computer using normal terminal in my PC but my question is if I am already logged in to the website and I want to copy a file to my local PC, do I need to put my computer IP address??

Here is easier to describe the problem:

```
scp kk.txt [my local pc]
```

now what should I substitute instead of [my local pc]??

Comment: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Comment: exactly that's my question. So imagine I am running the command in the server so I don't have the your_username@remotehost.edu. I am just send it to my local PC but as the command is executing on the server it has no information about my PC, I tried to use the IP address of my computer but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u have static ip - 
**scp kk.txt username@STATIC_IP:directory_to_copy_file**

e.g scp kk.txt user@1.2.3.4:~ (will copy it to ur home folder)

if you have dynamic ip, you can not scp from website to ur local pc, but you can do otherway round, like

**scp username@webiste_address:file_path ur_local_directory**
e.g. scp me@somesite.com:~/kk.txt .  (this will copy file kk.txt to your current directory)

the second approach is always recommended, as you dont have to worry about ur ip address, you just need to know the address of the remote site from where you are copying data.